# Angular Prerender Redirecting With Extra Slash

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, prerender

I'm using Angular Universal + Prerender. Here are the packages:

- "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^13.0.1"
- "@angular/core": "13.0.1"

I prerender all my routes, I have a few ones.

The problem is that I run `npm run prerender` and I deploy my app to production.

When I navigate to `https://myapp.com/products` due to the prerendered files it add an extra slash at the end of the url, so the new url is `https://myapp.com/products/`, and Angular redirects me to the normal url again `https://myapp.com/products`.

In my `server.ts` file I have the following to redirect from http to https:

```
function requireHTTPS(req: any, res: any, next: any) {
if (!req.secure && req.get('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development") {
    return res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
}
next();
```

}

And I use it this way (this has nothing to do with the extra slash):

```
server.use(requireHTTPS);
```

And I do not want to tell Express to do not do redirects. Just prevent prerender to add extra slash and make Angular to redirect.

I have lots of errors with SEO: Canonical points to redirect, 3XX redirect in sitemap, 3XX page receives organic traffic. And my site is not SEOlike.

I hope anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, I have lots of errors with SEO: Canonical points to redirect, 3XX redirect in sitemap, 3XX page receives organic traffic. And my site is not SEOlike.

Comment: Please mention this in the question to get better reach

Comment: @AmosIsaila did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: @amansoni211 No, I just removed prerender

Comment: Checkout my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73835009/5832236 short answer is upgrade Angular Universal above 11.1 and make sure your server routes all traffic to `main.js`

Comment: If that doesn't answer it can you show your whole `server.ts` and `httacess` or `web.config` whatever you use?

Comment: where are you hosting your site?

Comment: did you try just creating a route in express to handle the extra slash with a 200 redirect?